# Using MQTT for Blackberry/J2ME

Tags: blackberry, java-me, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I recently had a look at an excellent [blog](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) for using MQTT over Android. I am new to MQTT, and for understanding the concepts, I want to use MQTT services on Blackberry. Is there a good explanation of how MQTT works... a J2ME/ blackberry implementation will be easy to understand for me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM released Cordova MQTT plugin and source for Android via developerworks that wraps the Eclipse Paho mqtt java client (also IBM contributed).  If you're creating mobile apps then doing HTML5/javascript hybrid apps in Cordova (f.k.a. PhoneGap) with an MQTT plugin is a good to go.  On Android (i.e. BB playbook) there is this one.  For other platforms, using Eclipse Paho to create a plugin for Cordova on BB shouldn't be hard.  For example I have Cordova/Worklight apps with MQTT plugin using the Eclipse Paho C client on my iPhone.

here is the MQTT plugin for Android:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/messaging/entry/using_mq_telemetry_transport_protocol_in_ibm_worklight_mobile_applications1

MQTT is compelling for mobile apps.  Benchmarking done on Android showed that MQTT has 93x higher throughput, 1/10th batter use per message sent and uses 1/8th the bandwidth vs HTTPS.  This is probably why Facebook Messenger uses MQTT.  http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/1217

btw, If you do develop HTML5/javascript hybrid mobile apps with Cordova, IBM Worklight has a cross-platform WYSIWYG mobile developer IDE, strong security, unified push notification engine, online/offline support, etc. And Cordova is built-in.

Answer (score 3):

There's a brief description of some of the concepts behind mqtt at http://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html

The presentation at http://www.slideshare.net/andysc/the-house-that-twitters also contains explanations from more of an applications viewpoint.

As for J2ME - the IBM ia92 package linked from http://mqtt.org/software contains a J2ME component with API docs and example, but not the implementation code.

Lastly, the MQTT spec is linked to on http://mqtt.org/documentation so you can always look there for more details.